# AspectJ pointcut for parents class in Android

Tags: java, android, aspectj

Basically, I want to insert a `pointcut` for `onKeyDown()`, `onBackPressed()`, etc. methods. The problem is that in case these methods are not `overloaded`, `aspect` doesn't react. What is correct way to insert `pointcut` to get `Activities` (or other parents) method calls?

For now it looks like that:

```
pointcut onKeyDown(): execution(* onKeyDown(*, *));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't weave in Android core classes as the associated recompiled .class files would not be integrated in your application .dex file as they are provided directly by android.

As you proposed, you could overload these methods with a direct call to the overloaded method.

For the same reason, you can't use pointcuts weaving in core classes before calling custom code like:

```
call(* Activity.onCreate(..))
```

but you can use pointcuts weaving custom code being called like:

```
execution(* Activity.onCreate(..))
```